# Creating a Dependency Property on a User Control of type String but displayed in property browser as a combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

For my purposes a Enum will not work as a type because the possible values are not known at run-time.

I started with the info provided in the answer to [Create UserControl DependencyProperty of which value can be chosen in dropdown list (as combo box)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469010/create-usercontrol-dependencyproperty-of-which-value-can-be-chosen-in-dropdown-l) which was asking the same questions, but the user was satisfied by using an Enum and the answer using the type converter didn't get me very far.

My DP (pretty straightforward):

```
    [TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(DataSourceTypeConverter))]
    public string dataSource
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(dataSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(dataSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for dataSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty dataSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("dataSource", typeof(string), typeof(StatScreenDataElement), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

And the TypeConverter

```
public class DataSourceTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        List<string> dataSources = new List<string>();
        dataSources.Add("Test 1");
        dataSources.Add("Test 2");
        return new StandardValuesCollection(dataSources);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am not able to get the DP to show as a drop-down in the property browser and typing somthing into it returns:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'DataSourceTypeConverter cannot convert from System.String.'

Comment: There is no type conversion from string to string.

Comment: @Clemens do I need a new type derived from String? Even so, still dont get why a combo box doesnt show up, the error is only after trying to type into the field.

Comment: Don't know. I was just stumbling over the idea to have a TypeConverter for a string property that converts from string. Also, if possible values are not known at compile time, how is your TypeConverter supposed to be implemented?

Comment: I may be able to use a custom type and `UITypeEditor` to accomplish what i need, haven't found any solid documentation on it yet though.